# What is 'major' about the major term in logic?

Tags: logic, terminology

<sub>Source: p 264, *A Concise Introduction to Logic* (12 Ed, 2014), by Patrick J. Hurley</sub>

> Each of the three terms in a categorical syllogism has its own name depending on its
>   position in the argument. The **major term**, by definition, is the predicate of the conclusion,
>   and the **minor term** is the subject of the conclusion.

1. What is 'major'/'minor' about the **major term**/**minor term**?
2. How is 'the predicate of the conclusion' more major or less minor than 'the subject of the conclusion'?

I already tried to research of the etymologies of 'major' and 'minor' on OED, and the definitions of their etymons in Latin.

> [major (adj.)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/115320#eid37919469)
>   In use in Logic (see sense [B. 1](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112621?rskey=lcc9L9&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid38195624)) after post-classical Latin *major* (from a1225 in British sources, in Grosseteste, Bacon, Ockham, Wyclif, etc.) and Middle French *majour* (c1354), Middle French, French *majeure* (from the 14th cent.).
>
> [mājor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/major#Latin) = [māior](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maior#Latin) = 'greater, larger'
>
> [minor (adj.)](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/118931?rskey=cMN2gE&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)
>   With use as noun in logic denoting a minor premiss (see sense [B. 2](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/118931?rskey=cMN2gE&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid37014371)) compare post-classical Latin *minor* (feminine, from 13th cent. in British sources), Middle French *mineur* (feminine, 1373; French *mineure*, contrasted with *mineur* (masculine) denoting a minor term).
>
> [minor](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minor#Latin) = 'lesser, inferior, smaller'

<sub>Source: p 22, *With Good Reason, An Introduction to Informal Fallacies* (6 ed, 2000) by [Prof. S. Morris Engel PhD (Toronto)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Morris_Engel)</sub>

> Arguments of this type may lack either the statement of the general principle (called in logic the [M]ajor [P]remise), explicit reference to the case in question (the [M]inor [P]remise), or the inference (the conclusion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Aristotle's Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/) and [Medieval Theories of the Syllogism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-syllogism/) :

> In the *Prior Analytics*, Aristotle presents the first system of logic, the theory of the syllogism . A syllogism is a deduction consisting of three sentences: two premises and a conclusion. Syllogistic sentences are categorical sentences involving a subject and a predicate connected by a copula (verb).
>
> The subject and predicate in the categorical sentences used in a syllogism are called terms (*horoi*) by Aristotle. There are three terms in a syllogism: a major, a minor, and a middle term. The major and the minor are called the extremes (*akra*), i.e., the major extreme (*meizon akron*) and the minor extreme (*elatton akron*), and they form the predicate and the subject of the conclusion. The middle (*meson*) term is what joins the two premises.

Thus, the original technical Aristotelian names has been translated into Medieval Latin and the "current" terminology is of Latin origin.

---

Consider a simple example of [Aristotelian syllogism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-syllogism/#1) :

> Mortality belongs to all men
>
> Humanity belongs to all Greeks
>
> > Therefore, Mortality belongs to all Greeks.

It is an instance of the *Barbara* schema (1st figure), where all sentences are *universal affirmatives* :

> **A** belongs to all **B**.

Thus "Humanity (men)" is the *middle* term, used as subject in the first premise and as predicate in the second. The middle term is what joins the two premises, acting as a sort of "link", and disappears in the conclusion.

The name of *meson* ("middle") term is thus quite intuitive.

See [Prior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_Analytics), 25b32-26a2 :

> I call that term middle which both is itself in another and contains another in itself: in position also this comes in the middle. By extremes I mean both that term which is itself in another and that in which another is contained.

The other two are the *akra* ("extremes"); also this is quite natural.

The first extreme is the "major" (*meizon akron*) and the last one is the "minor" (*elatton akron*).

See [Prior Analytics](http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/prior.1.i.html), 26a16-26a30 :

> I call that term the major in which the middle is contained and that term the
> minor which comes under the middle.

In terms of "modern" set-theoretic interpretation (see [Venn diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) and [Venn Diagrams for Categorical Syllogisms](http://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/syll_venn.html)), the set corresponding to the *minor* term is included into that corresponding to the *middle*, which in turn is included into that corresponding to the *major* term.

In terms of aristotelian language, the major term is is "more universal" than the middle, which in turn is "more universal" than the minor:

> [*Pr.An.*, Book A, 46a39] In demonstrations, when there is a need to deduce that something belongs, the middle term through which the deduction is formed must always be inferior to and not comprehend the first of the extremes.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot see the answer to my question in the quote above, which only redirect my questions to Aristotle's motivations: What did Aristotle find 'major' in 'major term'? What did Aristotle find 'minor' in 'minor term'?

Comment: Sorry, no. I have not read Aristotle's works entirely; I am using this Logic textbook for now. Does Aristotle explain this himself in his book? If so, please tell me which pages and I will read them myself.

Comment: Thank you again. I understand the need to read the original texts. Sorry to bother you again, but will you please explain further the etymology behind `The first extreme is the "major" (meizon akron) and the last one is the "minor" (elatton akron)`? I still do not see what is 'major' or 'minor' about the Major and Minor Terms.

Comment: Also, I ask only about the Major and Minor Terms; I do understand the etymology behind 'Middle Term' and so no need to say anything more about it.