# Why did Aristotle describe as Extremes: the Major Term and Minor Term?

Tags: logic, terminology, aristotle

I have not (yet) studied Ancient Greek. [This comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/30937/8572) introduced me to the pertinence of Aristotle's *Prior Analytics*, but a translation below does not resolve my question entitled above.

<sub>Source: *Aristotle's Prior Analytics: Book I, Translated with an introduction and commentary* (2009) by Gisela Striker</sub>

> [page 4, Chapter 4, 25<sup>b</sup>, Lines 35-36]
>   Extremes are what is in another
>   and that in which there is another.
>
> [page 95] **25<sup>b</sup>35-37**   [...]  As a terminological introduction this is a little confusing, and so
>   the ancient commentators simply replace Aristotle's explanations by
>   the later definitions that hold for all three figures : the middle term
>   is the one that occurs in both premisses, the extremes are the terms
>   of the conclusion, with the predicate term being the greater (major),
>   the subject term the smaller (minor) . Again, the labels 'major' and
>   'minor' are presumably taken from the example of Barbara (see
>   below, 26<sup>a</sup> 21-3 ). One must admit that Aristotle's choice of labels is
>   unfortunate and possibly misleading, but it has served its purpose
>   well enough through the ages, and it obviously did not mislead
>   Aristotle himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said above the terminolgy is "fitted on" *Barbara*:

> "**A** belongs to all **B** and **B** belongs to all **C**; therefore..."

The "middle" (*meson*) is in the middle and major and minor are the "external" ones, called "extremes" (*akron*). This is not true for other figures.

Thus, the subsequent "revised" explanation: the *middle* is the term occurring in both premises.

*Note*:

- [akron](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Akron): Ancient Greek *ἄκρον* ‎(“extremity, peak”)
- [meson](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meson) : Ancient Greek *μέσον* ‎(“middle”).

  ---

See *Prior Analytics*, I, 25b32-26a2:

> Whenever three terms are so related to one another that the last is in the middle as in a whole, and the middle is either in, or not in, the first as in a whole, the extremes must be related by a perfect deduction [*sullogismos*]. I call that term middle which both is itself in another and contains another in itself: in position also this comes in the middle. By extremes I mean both that term which is itself in another and that in which another is contained.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how the above answers my question. Do you mean that because the Major and Minor occupy EXTERNAL positions, Aristotle called them EXTREME positions? Ie: Their externality was somehow considered as extremity? If so, why? Externality does not usually mean externality.

Comment: @LePressentiment - exactly: we say the "extremes" of an interval or segment, and not the "externals".